# Django - how to create auth system with custom models

Tags: python, django, django-models

django default auth system uses own auth models, but I have created my own model and i want, the auth process happens there

My model is :

```
class User(models.Model):
Nome = models.CharField(max_length=12)
Sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=12)
Nickname = models.CharField(max_length=21,unique=True)
Email = models.CharField(max_length=40)
Password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
Created_Account_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
Avatar = models.FileField(blank=True)
Number_Following = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=False)
Number_Followers = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=False)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s%s" %("@",self.Nickname)
```

## I want use it to make auth process , and not django's default

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, thank you man it helped ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely take a look at [Customizing Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) in the Django docs.

But I will try to break it down for you. You can follow along and add your specific fields:

First, to make a custom `User` model you need to inherit from `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`. Keep in mind that the former provides more functionality than the latter and also requires less customization. So If you are not too familiar with Django's authentication system then I advise you inherit from `AbstractUser` to avoid unnecessary customization.

**Example:**

So let's say you want to extend the standard user model and add an `EmailField`.

```
#models.py 'users' app
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

Now we need to let Django know to use our brand new CustomUser model.
so at our settings file we can go ahead and add:

```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

You may want to have users provide an E-mail address when they register. For that you also need to customize your `UserCreationForm` so in our forms file:

```
#forms.py
from users.models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)
    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Afterwards you need to go ahead and register your newly created `CustomUser` model in your `admin.py`.

You will most likely need to make a custom `UserChangeForm`. And possibly a custom authentication backend(If you want users to login with e-mail for example.) But that probably deserves a new question by its own.

I strongly suggest you read the Django authentication docs(The link at the top). It will give you a better guidance to do the proper customization you for your specific needs.

Alternatively, If you feel this is too complicated at the moment you can also consider creating a separate model with the custom fields you need and then declaring a `OneToOneField` to link between the standard `User` model and your new model.

Best of luck!